# I cant display data in textbox for update data using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework. *I am trying for edit data*, I can't display data in text box, first step of update data. My controller is `sitecontroller.php`, my view file `update-jobseeker.php`. I have 5 tables `user`, `job_seeker_profile`, `job_profile`, `location`, and `category`.

I got the error `"Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\yii_new\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1414"`

My controller is `sitecontroller`, it's action is:

```
<?php
public function actionupdate_jobseeker()
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $model = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('user u')
        ->join('job_seeker_profile s','u.id = s.user_id')
        ->join('job_profile j','u.id = j.user_id')
        ->join('location l','l.id = s.location_id')
        ->join('category c','c.id = j.category_id')
        ->where('u.id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
        ->QueryAll();
    $this->render('update_jobseeker',array('model' =>$model));
}
?>
```

My view file is `update_jobseeker.php`

```
<div>
   <div style="float:right;margin-right:285px;">
   <h1>Update Personal Detail</h1>
   <div class="form">
       <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
           'id'=>'login-form',
           'enableClientValidation'=> false,
            'htmlOptions' => array(),
            'clientOptions'=> array(
                'validateOnSubmit'=> true
             ),
        )); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Mobile No'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'contact_no'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'contact_no'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
 </div>
```

Anybody help me?

Comment: in here `$model` is an array not an obejct, use active record instead

Comment: hi,I had edited the code in view file,plz look it...

Answer (score 0):

if your model name is User, then the Active records find would be like:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->join = 'job_seeker_profile s On t.id = s.user_id
    inner join job_profile j ON t.id = j.user_id
    inner join location l ON l.id = s.location_id
    inner join category c ON c.id = j.category_id';
$criteria->compare('t.id' , id);

$model = User::model()->find($criteria);
```

Comment: it's the default alias for main table, in here it's alias for user table

Comment: Now i have the error "CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;"